# Не создается папка при скачивании

Tags: android, android-studio

Если отсутствует созданная папка, то файлы не скачиваются. Помогите плз

```
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folder6/";
                InputStream in = MyApplication.getContext().getAssets().open("wallpaper/" + wp.getWp());

                File outFile = new File(path, wp.getWp());
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                MyApplication.getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(outFile)));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте её:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folder6/";
File dir = new File(path);
if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdir(); // или mkdirs(), если нужно создать несколько вложенных
// работаем дальше
```

Comment: Только dir.mkdir(); но проблему понял, огромное спасибо)

Comment: Да, только не нужно работать дальше, если не создана директория =))